# Working with XML data from Python API request

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, elementtree

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API, however it appears to be returning in XML format.

```
response = requests.get('https string')
print(response.text)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><RegisterSearch TotalResultsOnPage="500" TotalResults="15167" TotalPages="31" PageSize="500" CurrentPage="1"><SearchResults><Document DocumentId="1348828088640186163"/><Document DocumentId="1348828088751561003"/></SearchResults></RegisterSearch>
```

I've tried using `ElementTree` as suggested by other answers, but receive a `file not found` error. I think I'm missing something.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(response.text)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: `response.text` is a string, not a file. Use `ET.fromstring()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

If you want to use ElementTree You need to parse from STRING

```py
root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
```

You can parse it with Beautiful Soup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')
```

Then depending on what you want to find or extract you can use find

```py
soup.find('DocumentId').text
```